# How to create a chunk in 3D world?

Tags: java, minecraft, voxel

i am working on voxel based game engine, in which i need to have chunks. I have tried to read a Chunk class from minecraft, but i cant understand it. 
By chunk i mean: 16x16x256 array of blocks

So my question is: How chunk works and how does it store data?

Comment: Not everybody here has read into the Minecraft codebase, a chunk may be anything from a piece of memory buffer to a geometrical structure to some entirely different. What is the chunk you're referring to? What are you trying to do. What did you try so far? Can you show us your nonworking code?

Comment: I dont have a nonworking code, cause i dont even understand how i should do it.

Comment: @datenwolf A chunk is related to voxel graphics in general I believe not just minecraft specific

Comment: @TheMorfeus: Then I suggest you learn. StackOverflow can help you if you're stuck with a specific topic, but such a broad question simply doesn't fit the QA format of it.

Comment: @TheMorfeus  I recommend not looking at other code, think what Is a chunk? and how can I simply represent it in a class first.

Comment: @Sam Giles That's what i am trying to do, but i can't figure out how this can work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> By chunk i mean: 16x16x256 array of blocks

Well, that defies some geometrical structure then. If this is a Micraft-esque game, then a block is either filled, or it's void. Do you want those blocks be of different types, or just "there" or "not there".

Lets say, for the sake of simplicity, that you want to have 2^CHAR_BIT different states for a block (CHAR_BIT is 8 on most systems). The state 0 means void. So you can store those blocks in a array of the structure

```
char chunk[16][16][256];
```

You can encapsulate this in a class.

```
class Chunk
{
private:
    char chunk[16][16][256];
}
```

Of course your world consists of more than one chunk, you'll probably arrange your chunks in a grid, where each grid cell takes up one chunk

```
class ChunkGrid
{
private:
    std::list<Chunk> chunks;
```

And for sure you also want to organize those Chunks in a spatial subdivision structure, so that you can quickly index chunks depending on their position in the world, a Octree works wonderfully for that

```
    class ChunkOctree
    {
    private:
        union Fork
        {
            ChunkOctree *branch;
            Chunk *leaf;
        };
        Fork forking[2][2][2];
    }
```

you'll also want some functions to traverse this structure, but I'll leave the research up to you, as a learning experimence. I've given you plenty of keywords to search the interwebs for.

```
}
```

Comment: Great, but is that even java?

Comment: there is already a c++ tutorial for that somewhere. thats why i was asking question under java tag.

Comment: @TheMorfeus: Consider this pseudocode. Conceptually there's no difference between C++, Java or D regarding those things. As a learner it is important for you, that you're looking beyond the language used and understand the underlying concepts and data structures.

Comment: yeah. even though its not java it helped me understand few things. thanks :)